# Amplifier settings for Epiphone Standard Pro Top

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

Hello Ive been struggling with my amp settings for quite a bit now. My amp happens to be a Roland cube 40 and I'm still intermediate at playing so I still don't have a processor or any other effect pedal. So my problem is that I dont get the long lasting smooth distortion tone. For example consider the solo of wither by Dream Theatre or Farewell Ballad by Zakk Wylde. Do I need to put the gain at its max (I usually get a rough sound with that)?

Could anyone suggest me good settings for the amp without the need for processor or any other effect pedal.
Thanks

Comment: Sustain originates in the string and guitar construction itself, you mention an Epiphone. I have the same guitar and can tell you the sustain is not that great. All I can think of for you to get is some sort of e-bow device. Opinions differ on what makes sustain greater/shorter but novice/intermediate guitars aren't typically built for sustain.

Comment: Actually I think its not about the sustain coz' when my amp is in JC Clean it has a very long and good sustain but I dont find that when distorting it.

Comment: In that case the distorted patch in the Cube may have a gate element to it cutting off any signal below a certain dB threshold.

Comment: So do I need to decrease gain and increase volume can you suggest me where the gain and volume should be set in that case?

Comment: Yeah, set the gain at 0 and go from there. It's all a matter of personal taste and experimentation really, gain shouldn't generally be maxed out unless you're going for a ridiculous tone :D

Comment: Ill definitely try that but in most cases (all till now) my lower strings sound very heavy making the notes I play 'not crispy' or clear.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, increasing the gain will improve your sustain - and taking gain up so far it dramatically clips the input signal will act as a compressor and increase gain.

[Petrucci also uses a dynamics processor and a range of very good valve amplifiers and effects](http://www.rig-talk.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=175765)...Some pictures from that site:

[image]
[image]

These allow greater sustain and controlled feedback without excessive noise.

With your current guitar and amp you may just not be able to achieve the same tone.

Here's a [logical structure for Petrucci's rig](https://www.guitar.com/rigs/john-petrucci-dream-theater-2002-rig-and-gear-setup?v=fullsize) - this can also help you understand just how different your kit is from his:

[image]

Comment: My guitar seems to make noise at lower strings its just not thin and crisp. Cant I adjust my amp so that atleast I get a good tone? Or atleast close to many guitarists on youtube

Comment: Once you find the guitar and amp that work for you, stick with it - all guitarists struggle to find 'their' tone. After 28-ish years gigging, I have finally found the amp that gives me the tone I like, and I have played everything under the sun. Some amps just won't do what you need.

Comment: Im just curious that are there some sounds that actually need processor and cannot be made without them?

Comment: and maybe thats the reason why I dont get specific sounds?

Comment: Of course there are many sounds that need processors, but get your guitar and amp combo right first.